React Native Bottom Sheet Change Bar Color
How would I change the color of top bar of the bottom sheet modal? I looked in the documentation and in the package it's self but don't see anything to change it. I tried changing the backgroundColor but that didn't work as well.
<BottomSheetModal
  ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
  index={0}
  snapPoints={snapPoints}
  onChange={handleSheetChanges}>
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: Colors.darkMode.cards1,
    }}>
    <Pressable
      style={{
        flexGrow: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 9,
        paddingVertical: 4,
        paddingHorizontal: 2,
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}>
      <Text
        style={{
          color: Colors.gtechGold,
          fontSize: 17,
          fontFamily: 'RobotoSlab-Medium',
        }}>
        Test
      </Text>
    </Pressable>
  </View>
</BottomSheetModal>



You can modify two properties that change the top bar color on the bottom sheet, handleStyle and handleIndicatorStyle.
 <BottomSheetModal
  ..."your props"
  handleIndicatorStyle={{backgroundColor:"red"}}
  handleStyle={{backgroundColor:"red"}}
  >
      ...."your code"...
</BottomSheetModal>

